# Android Studio Release build gives me: Unfortunately, “App Name” has stopped

Tags: android, build, android-studio, release, signing

I'm working on Android Studio 1.1.0.
The build variant `debug` works perfectly but when I tried to run the `release` build variant the app starts but gives me an "Unfortunately, “App Name” has stopped."

I already signed my apps in the past, maybe I'm missing a simple step which I completely forgot, what have I missed?

This is my `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.madx.quiz.apf"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file('/Users/madx/Documents/Workspaces/Android/APF/app/keystore.keystore')
            storePassword ‘my_store_password’
            keyAlias ‘my_key_alias’
            keyPassword ‘my_key_password’
        }
        debug {}
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            zipAlignEnabled true
        }
        debug {
        }
    }
}

repositories{
// some repositories
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
}
```

Event log gives me:

```
19:52:49 Gradle build finished in 3 sec
19:52:50 Session 'app': running
```

Logcat:

```
03-02 19:33:11.851  25913-25913/com.madx.quiz.apf I/art﹕ Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
03-02 19:33:12.840  25913-25946/com.madx.quiz.apf D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Render dirty regions requested: true
03-02 19:33:12.849  25913-25913/com.madx.quiz.apf D/Atlas﹕ Validating map...
03-02 19:33:12.922  25913-25946/com.madx.quiz.apf I/Adreno-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: QUALCOMM Build: 10/24/14, 167c270, I68fa98814b
03-02 19:33:12.924  25913-25946/com.madx.quiz.apf I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
03-02 19:33:12.936  25913-25946/com.madx.quiz.apf D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
```

Gradle console:

```
Executing tasks: [:app:generateReleaseSources]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild
:app:preReleaseBuild
:app:checkReleaseManifest
:app:preDebugBuild
:app:prepareComAfollestadMaterialDialogs0612Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72103Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV132100Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42103Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGithubDanielemaddalunoAndroidupdatecheckerLibrary102Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareReleaseDependencies
:app:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeReleaseResources
:app:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processReleaseResources
:app:generateReleaseSources

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 2.4 secs
```

Comment: How do you expect us to help you with no stacktrace nor relevant code?

Comment: Android Studio doesn't return me any info about the stop error... I don't know why. I hope someone else have already had the same problem.

Comment: How ever I added in the question my Event Log, Logcat and Gradle console outputs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try disabling ProGuard in your release build:

`build.gradle` :

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        zipAlignEnabled true
    }
    debug {
    }
}
```

The problem is probably caused by ProGuard, but without the stacktrace, I can't really fix your problem.

I you still want to use proguard I suggest you to look for more information about the error, you can add in the release field the following:

```
debuggable true
jniDebuggable true
```

So you can better identify the problem.
However probably the problem is linked to gson library, you should add to the `proguard-rules.pro` file the following lines (you could check a more complex example [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/source/browse/trunk/examples/android-proguard-example/proguard.cfg)):

```
# Add any classes the interact with gson
-keepclassmembers class com.madx.quiz.apf.apf.APFQuestion { *; }
-keepclassmembers class com.madx.quiz.apf.apf.APFSubCategory { *; }

###---------------Begin: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields. Proguard
# removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
-keepattributes Signature

# For using GSON @Expose annotation
-keepattributes *Annotation*

# Gson specific classes
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
#-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }

# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { *; }

##---------------End: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
```

Comment: I tried to leave only the minimal `signingConfig signingConfigs.release` inside the release fileld but nothing changes, I already get the same error

Comment: The LogCat output you posted is not complete, I can't help you without the stacktrace. Run `adb logcat` in terminal, and find the stack trace, and post it.

Comment: OK I was wrong the problem was the proguard... I had to add a rule for Gson library... Let me modify your answer with the complete steps to solve it. If you accept my edit I'll check your answer!

Comment: Nice to see that your problem is solved :-)  Would be nice to accept my answer. Thanks for the edit.